# My app is not receiving silent notifications (background & foreground both)

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I am working on one app which uses silent notification as UI update and app content update but couldn't receive silent notification in app in both state background & foreground

Earlier it was working fine when we were sending batch with payload but it was creating issue notification used to clear automatically. Thanks in advance

Want to receive silent notification as it's need of time to update app content

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.